# Highcharts change dataset

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This question uses the Highcharts API. I am developing a chart using Highcharts that populates based upon a user's option select. This feature works exactly as I intend, except for a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` error at the specific line below:

```
 update[t].addPoint(listrepeat.classmakeup[t].studentsize);
```

My JSFiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/4ufoj5cx/1/

The code works perfectly. However, I would like to know what I am doing wrong that is causing this error message to show on my console.

Comment: I am not getting any error in console for fiddle you have provided ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes because of repeated `setInterval` on change of `select`. You have to use `clearInterval()` to clear previous `setInterval`. Rest everything is fine.

```
function opmiddle(listreader){
    classcat.addEventListener('change', function(){
        opend(listreader);
        clearInterval(previousInterval); //you have to clear previous setInterval 
  });
  classcat.innerHTML += "<option>--</option>";
  for (i = 0; i < listreader.school.length; i++){
    classcat.innerHTML += "<option>"+listreader.school[i].directory+"</option>";
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0r9xazq/) demonstration